# Why does the research assistant "go get it" link take you to your "interesting tags" settings, on sci-fi.stackexchange?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, badges

When I tried to get the 'research assistant' badge on sci-fi, it linked me to [this 'interesting tags' page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/3804#interesting-tags).

But on meta it sends me to three [tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) pages.

I've confirmed this isn't a moderator thing, based on [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28469790#28469790), and [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28469805#28469805)

Why is that? Is scifi special?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that link isn't visible to someone who isn't a mod on SFF...

Comment: @Rand I think you're right,  on here it's linked to the tags page

Answer (score 2):

Research Assistant requires you to edit 50 tag wikis. Tag wikis are supposed to be thoughtful introductions to a topic, which are therefore best written by someone who is at least vaguely knowledgeable about the topic.

Your favorite/interested tags are presumably at least correlated with topics you know something about. Hence, linking you to your preferred tags is a good place for you to start editing tag wikis that you know something about.

Comment: I figured that tangential relationship,  but it seemed an odd place to start. I was going it'd take me to a page like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new)

Comment: @Pureferret That would perhaps make more sense, but I guess they figure you're less likely to have expertise there.

Comment: it looked like it's just on scifi.